# sublime text 3 и emmet

Tags: вёрстка, sublime-text-3, emmet

Всем привет! 
Столкнулся с некой проблемой, по вёрстке шаблонов.
Когда я например пишу:
[image]

и жму на таб, разворачивается код в виде:
[image]

после чего жму на интер и получаю:

[image]

в чём собственно суть проблемы, как сделать так, что бы после нажатия на интер получилось так:
[image]

надеюсь подробно описал :)

Comment: нажать на ентер ещё раз ))

Comment: не помогает, получается так:
http://i.stack.imgur.com/P911U.png
не удобно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, что то сбилось в настройках emmet. Самым действенным вариантом будет, удалить emmet  и поставить заново.